# Data not appearing in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to `INSERT` data into my `SQL` database but its not showing anything at all.

This is a for an online role-playing game . There is no error but when I refresh my browser for `phpmyadmin` using `XAMP`, no data is being shown.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string checkDatabase = "select * from players where username = @playerName";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(checkDatabase, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerName", player.SocialClubName);

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.Read())
            {
                player.SendChatMessage("There is an account with the assiociated Social Club Profile!");
            }
            else
            {

                    MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                    connection1.Open();
                    string playerInsert = "insert into players(username,password) VALUES (@user,@password)";
                    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(playerInsert, connection1);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", player.SocialClubName);
                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                    connection1.Close();

            }

            connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute the query. Try:

```
...
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's cause you are not executing the query at all as can be seen in below posted code

```
             string playerInsert = "insert into players(username,password) VALUES (@user,@password)";
                MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand(playerInsert, connection1);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", player.SocialClubName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the query
                connection1.Close();
```

Comment: I think whoever dv'd didn't interpret the question correctly

Comment: Thank you guys! It works like a charm. How silly me to forget about that one line.